# How to *not* get readonly records in ActiveRecord 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, readonly

I have code similar to this:

```
MyTable.where(something: 'abc').each do |rec|
  rec.some_attr = 123
  rec.save!
end
```

Please take extra note that I am querying and changing `MyTable` only, relations are not involved. `something` and `some_attr` are plain ActiveRecord attributes, nothing fancy.

The `MyTable` model is rather complex with many relations of all kinds.

My problem is that the `rec`s are having the `readonly` flag set, so I get an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` when saving.

A workaround is to clear the readonly flag:

```
rec.instance_variable_set(@readonly, false)
```

After this, saving works correctly; it smells fishy though.

### Question 1

I understand that ActiveRecord has some cases where it explicitly makes returned records readonly (e.g. for 1:n relationships where there is no clear way to update something), just like you can, for example, not update certain attributes of a view in Oracle. What could prompt it to make the "base" record of the query itself readonly though? I'd assume that this can always be trivially updated.

The only documentation I could find on this is in the `readonly?` API:

> Records loaded through joins with piggy-back attributes will be marked as read only since they cannot be saved.

What are "piggy-back attributes"?

### Question 2

Is there a way to disable the `readonly` flag in the query itself? `find` and other methods seem to have a `readonly` option (though it is unclear whether `readonly: false` is acceptable, or if it is only there for the `readonly: true` case to make an otherwise writable record readonly). I tried that with `where` to no success.

The solution from [How to replace find by readonly on newer Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542623/how-to-replace-find-by-readonly-on-newer-rails) does not work:

```
MyTable.readonly(false).where(something: 'abc').each do |rec|  # seems to be a no-op

MyTable.where(something: 'abc').readonly(false).each do |rec|  # same
```

Thanks in advance!